# zoom inside a width fixed div

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to enable a `div` zoomable **&** scrollable inside a **width-fixed** `div` when using `transform: scale(aScaleRatio)` to *zoom in/out*.

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahhi4a) to achieve the *zoom in/out*. But the **inner** div just cannot present itself properly *top-left-aligned* even I tried to align it with `position: absolute; top: 0; left:0`.

Any idea will be appreciated :)

```html
<html>
<body>
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 800px; position: absolute; top: 100px">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 16px; z-index: 2;">
    <!---something else--->
  </div>
  <!--- this is the scrollable outer div --->
  <div
    style="width:3000px; background-color:red; height: 2000px; z-index: 1; overflow: auto;"
  >
    <!--- I am trying to zoom this div in/out --->
    <!--- sadly I cannot align it within the outer div --->
    <div
    style="position: absolute; transform: scale(1.2); background-color: black; width: 500px; height: 400px; top: 0; left: 0;"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or how can I show the `11111` in this [pen](https://codepen.io/Hearen/pen/MZGXgp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed this is what you want: [fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRjXqW)

Could be achieved by replacing `transform-origin: left;` into `transform-origin: 0% 0%;`

From your snippet demo:

```html
<html>
<body>
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 800px; position: absolute; top: 100px">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 16px; z-index: 2;">
    <!---something else--->
  </div>
  <!--- this is the scrollable outer div --->
  <div
    style="width:3000px; background-color:red; height: 2000px; z-index: 1; overflow: auto;"
  >
    <!--- I am trying to zoom this div in/out --->
    <!--- sadly I cannot align it within the outer div --->
    <div
    style="position: absolute; transform: scale(1.2); background-color: black; width: 500px; height: 400px;  transform-origin: 0% 0%;"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) to learn more about `transform-origin`

Comment: Thank you so much, just start the journey in `CSS` stuff...so tiresome adjusting it instead of using **UI** libraries.